# How do I write a unit test that verifies a subroutine is called?

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing

```
Public Class Class1

Public OutPut As String = ""
Public StoreThis As String = ""

Public Function GiveOutPut(ByVal s As String) As String

    OutPut = s + " OutPut"

    If s = "S" Then
        CallThis()
    End If

    Return OutPut

End Function

Public Sub CallThis()

    ///pretend something useful is going on here

End Sub

End Class
```

Granted this example is pretty weak, but how could I write a test method that to prove that CallThis() gets called everytime that the input parameter s = "S"?

Answer (score 3):

If something useful happens in `CallThis`, you can detect the side effect in your test code.

For example, if a variable changes value in a specific way by this function, you can test its value before and after the call.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is the best approach, but I would set a class-level boolean variable which the second subroutine would set, and then check that variable in the test.  Something like this:

```
Public Class Class1  

Public OutPut As String = "" 
Public StoreThis As String = "" 
Public Success as Boolean = False

   Public Function GiveOutPut(ByVal s As String) As String      
       OutPut = s + " OutPut"      
       If s = "S" Then
         CallThis()
       End If
       Return OutPut
   End Function

   Public Sub CallThis()
     ///pretend something useful is going on here
     Success = True
   End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Tools like NCover or TFS Code Coverage will anaysis what bits of your code have been called.  You could also use debug.writeline for ouput in your test.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have CallThis make some kind of outside effect that you can test on. If you code this yourself, then use a variable scoped e.g. in the class, before calling the CallThis method, set this variable to false, then inside the CallThis method, set it to true - and then thest that it has become true in the test.

Answer (score 0):

Use an isolation framework such as Rhino Mocks or Moq